# Ubuntu LTS 18.04 suddenly stuck at GRUB command line

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I followed this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line)'s solution, and I still can't fix it.

when I pressed `ls` , this is what it shows

```
(lvm/ubuntu--vg-swap_1) (lvm/ubuntu--vg-root) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

I tried

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

I also tried

`grub> linux /vml`<kbd>Tab</kbd>
`grub> initrd /in`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

but nothing showed up.

The next thing I tried is to use boot-repair, and this is the [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5dRbDSFzpW/) to the pastebin. After I reboot, it still stuck at GNU GRUB.

**Update:**
Try reinstall Ubuntu and it stuck on black screen after the grub menu. It will only boot up on recovery mode. Also try installing AMD drivers and do dist-upgrade it still stuck on black screen.

Comment: Please advise the distro you installed (i.e., Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, et al.) and its version. Please click [edit] and add that information to your question; please do not use Add Comment.