# When installing 18.04 alongside Windows 10, Grub is booted

Tags: system-installation, uefi, windows-10

I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 10 (Windows home N, version 10.0.18362 Build 18362). The system is UEFI based and the partition I want to install it on is 150GB, GPT based. I did format an USB drive with Rufus, UEFI, GPT-based and ubuntu 18.04. Whatever I do, I always get the Grub prompt while the information uptill now suggests I boot into the life environment. I tried to install from DVD, no luck either.

Quick restart is disabled. Is there a way to boot from USB into Ubuntu? If not, what should I do when in the Grub prompt?

Comment: What brand/model system? Acer needs you to set "Trust".  HP only accepts changes in boot order in UEFI settings not efibootmgr which grub uses to add/change its boot entries. Others may need other settings. Have you updated UEFI and if SSD updated SSD firmware? Many systems need that also.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the grub boot menu, there will be 2 options for booting from usb.
One is legacy boot and one is uefi.
Boot the uefi one.I had the same problem.
This helped me.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any menu, just the "grub> " command prompt.

Comment: [See this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line)

Comment: send the output from your grub windows and edit your post for that