# How to quit `cat` in grub terminal pre-boot

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2

In grub terminal (prior to system booting, in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line) situation), I have entered `cat <a file that was a program? something not human-readable>`.

Screenfuls of characters are now being output. Every now and then it stops, outputting `--MORE--`. What key/s do I press to make it quit `cat`? I've tried <kbd>q</kbd> , <kbd>Q</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> , <kbd>n</kbd> , <kbd>N</kbd> and random others that I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with that scenario but usually <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd> sends the quit signal (and produces a core dump)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in grub the system is in read-only mode and nothing is being written to the disk so the quickest method of restarting is to hold the power button for 10 seconds until your system powers off. Then press the power button once to restart grub.