# PC boots to grub console after booting Windows, but `exit` still leads to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 20.04, windows-10

I have a Dell Precision 5540. I decided to try my hand at installing Ubuntu 20.04 as a dual-boot with the pre-installed Windows 10, and at first, it worked. It rebooted to Grub following the installation, and I could select Ubuntu to boot to my new install. After Ubuntu booted successfully, I again rebooted to Grub, still working as normal, and booted to Windows Boot Manager. Windows 10 also loaded fine.

Here's the weird part: after rebooting from Windows 10, I'm brought to the Grub console (Normal `grub>` not `grub rescue>`). I googled around for some steps to repair the installation and did my best to follow the steps I found, but alas, my `/boot` folder appears to be empty. I cannot find vmlinuz or intrd.img. Furthermore, typing `exit` boots to Windows, and it boots just fine.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this? I apologize for my vagueness - I don't know how much/what I'm able to provide in terms of details. I'll be more than happy to supply any missing information.

The steps I followed are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line)

Thank you.