# How can I recover my hard disk and the boot menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I previously (to this day) had a 1TB hard drive (D), within which I had a partition for ubuntu and kali linux, but most of the time it was on ubuntu.

Yesterday because of the rush, I was in Ubuntu and I turned off the computer from the shutdown button. At noon I tried to turn it on but the boot menu no longer appeared, only the GRUB console and I could not exit unless I executed the "exit" command.

It sends me to Windows, I check the disks and there was only this one (C), I went straight to the console to check the partitions and it wasn't there either. I still do not understand how everything was erased (visually, because I know that everything is stored somewhere in the computer's memory.

I've tried this kind of solution but can't find a solution due to I don't find/have this line:
`linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20`

[Stuck at GRUB command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line)

I do not know if the MBR or the boot loader was damaged, I am interested in recovering only certain things although later I have to restore everything, some advice.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: But the thing it's since I turned off my pc from the shutdown button (while I was on linux), I have not been able to have access to the boot menu neither ubuntu.
Also, my disk partitions disappeared and I just have OS(C) with windows.

And now, every time I turn on my pc, the first thing I got it's the grub console without the boot menu.

Someone told me I've to reinstall linux and see a way to reconstruct the start system.

Comment: Without knowing what you did to get to this stage, it's going to be difficult to help you get out of it.