# Stuck in grub prompt after installing Windows in VM and removing it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

After I installed and uninstalled Windows in VM(in Ubuntu 20.04) when I rebooted my laptop , I am stuck in the grub prompt.I looked into [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line) but

```
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

This didn't do much change as I couldn't find grub file inside any of the folder inside every partition.
And then I tried this but couldn't find the kernel

```
grub> linux /vml Tab
grub> initrd /in Tab
```

Comment: I am using  Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I can't see how any change done in a VM makes any difference on the HOST OS (which I take as being Ubuntu 20.04 desktop?), however I would think it's more likely some other changes you made during your last session unrelated to a VM so details of what you did may help (did you install any packages? remove any packages, esp. make any partition changes etc)

Comment: I think KVM affects the kernel so but i'm not sure