# Help on booting ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I was trying to copy an old SSD to a new SSD and used "dd" to copy over, but I decided to stick to the old SSD and when I booted it didn't boot but I saw the grub console. At that time if I select prefix and root manually following [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line) it worked just fine.

But I wanted to fix the root cause of this problem and so I used Gparted and I am sorry I can't remember what exactly I had done.

I have somehow messed up the boot on my linux box and I haven't been able to boot ubuntu 20.04. I believe I still have the OS in the harddrive. Every time after I turn on I see "grub" console like this:

```
grub>
```

I can see (hd0,gpt2) and (hd0,gpt1)

but when I tried

```
grub>ls (hd0,gpt2)

Partition hd0,gpt1: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at ...
```

The same message for hd0,gpt2

I can't also do

```
grub>ls (hd0,gpt2)/
```

My question is how can I boot linux and fix this issue ?

I have been struggling with this issue for quite some time now and I want to fix it ASAP :(

Thank you.

**Updates**
As per suggestion I created a USB drive which contains ubuntu and booted this ubuntu and ran boot-repair.

Please see the boot info below

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W2qTpCYVJd/

Also from the console I see

On the console I typed "sudo fdisk -l" and I see

```
Disk /dev/sda: 447.13 GiB...
...
...
Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1 2048 1050623 1048576 512M EFI System
/dev/sda2 1050624 937701375 446.6G Linux filesystem
```

This is the ubuntu I want to boot :(

*Update 2*
I got another external hard drive and install ubuntu on it and booted. On it I installed Boot Repair and the Recommended Repair button appeared and it said it fixed but the summary is here below...

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gHMszZBmvN/

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "somehow messed up"? What were you doing? Partition editing? Software updating? Kernel hacking? If you have an Ubuntu installationUSB/DVD, you can check to ensure your data partitions are intact by booting with that and using something like GParted to view partition/volume information.

Comment: @matigo I added more description. I tried to upgrade to a bigger SSD so I had to copy from the old one to the new one. So if I use ubuntu installation USB can I still use the operating system I have on this solid state drive ? Could you please elaborate ? I am stuck :(

Comment: Do you still have both drives plugged in. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs & GUIDS and reboot without having issues. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I don't have two drives plugged in. I have formatted the new one so I only have the old one whose boot partition is messed up. How Could I run the boot-info summary report while this ssd can't be booted ?

Comment: @oldfred I put the link to the boot info above. I see it says "No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda"

Comment: First Boot-Repair report is not even seeing sda, just your  flash drive. It looks like you reinstalled grub and it created new correct UEFI boot entry for Ubuntu. You should not have an old BIOS boot loader in MBR. Not sure why so many NTFS not found. It does that if it cannot see partitioning, assuming it is a hibernated Windows that it then cannot see. Does Ubuntu entry now work?