# i don't have access to desktop GUI anymore

Tags: 20.04

i was stupidly repairing driver issue using this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure
i think i was here

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm3 ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm3 ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status || ubuntu-security-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami
```

and i might  issued "reboot" before the troubleshooting commands finished, i have access to xfce session but not graphical interface, when i boot the pc ( hooked to the TV) I'm faced with GNU GRUB i tried to go to recovery mode and file check and file repair without luck, i tried this [Stuck at GRUB command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line) with no luck too!!
i have root access to the terminal through xfce session which i run from my laptop using Chrome remote desktop, the monitor hooked to pc is black blank with little white blinking dash in top left corner
ETA:i can run xfce remotely, but I can't Access Ubuntu desktop (native GUI ie. the PC)
i can access tty2-4 and login but when i switch back to to tty1  i have black screen

Comment: Can you get to [a TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Xfce](https://www.xfce.org/) is a GUI desktop; so it's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: :i can run xfce remotely, but I can't Access Ubuntu desktop (native GUI ie. the PC)

Comment: simply run: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gdm3 gnome-shell`.

Comment: @someone task would be better - `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^ gdm3 gnome-shell` .

Comment: @N0rbert It will install a lot of packages though. Are you sure it is good reinstalling task package? It is probably 700mb above, right?

Comment: We do not know what is broken. So we should fix it in massive way :)

Comment: @N0rbert I like "massive" ;)

Comment: @N0rbert What is correct syntax for `dpkg -i --force ./deb` ?

Comment: On low level serious breakages I use `dpkg -i --force-all ./package-name.deb` then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall package-name` . Let's keep on-topic and wait for reaction from OP.