# No signal after `sudo update-grub`

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, hdmi

Had issue of booting to grub command line [Stuck at GRUB command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line) so ran suggestion of `sudo update-grub` and then did a reboot.

Now computer fan come on but absolute no signal. No bios, grub or ubuntu signal. Am plugged into HDMI of external graphic card, ubuntu 20.04 and windows 10 dual boot.

Before `sudo update-grub` had asrock bios appeared, then grub command line.

Very much https://xkcd.com/349/ moment.

Comment: The BIOS not appearing has absolutely nothing to do with GRUB (or any part of Ubuntu). If the BIOS splash screen do not appear, you have other issues, such as hardware error. Try with another HDMI cable first, then the internal or another graphics card for starters (now you're moving into hardware troubleshooting territory).

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you, got it to boot to bios by unplugging one hard disk and switching to display port. Just switching display port didn't work but unplugging windows hdd did.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to boot to bios and then grub recovery by unplugging one ssd and switching to display port (hdmi may still work, not tested as working).