# How to fix the grub environment issue?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had two OSs as a dual boot on my laptop i.e. Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10. My laptop is Acer Spin3. I wanted to reset factory in Windows 10 and delete all data on all drives. So initially, in Windows, I formatted the drive on which Ubuntu was installed. Then when I started the reset factory in Windows, the device restarted as a part of the reset process. But it rebooted in the grub environment with the following message:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completion. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1175786/1628487). The only place I could find some things related to grub was in `ls (hd0,1)/efi/ubuntu/` and the command displayed `grubx64.efi  shimx64.efi  mmx64.efi  bootx64.csv  grub.cfg`. Then I followed the answer, but nothing happened. The answer says the system reboots but my system didn't.

How should I fix the issue?

Comment: If you removed Ubuntu then it doesn't make much sense asking here, does it? What you need to learn is how to manage the boot process in UEFI settings > Boot menu where you can select "Windows" again. This will boot Windows directly however it won't remove the old Ubuntu entry from the ESP (EFI System Partition). This is irrelevant anyway but if you want you can than ask at superuser.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: @guiverc I already fixed it. The answer you suggested doesn't help with the question I had. I fixed it as follows. I accessed the bios and chose windows as the initial boot. Then after reboot, the windows started resetting. When installation finished, inside cmd as the admin, I followed the instructions of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/1628487) to remove grub. As a result, ubuntu was not available in the bios boot menu any more.