# Stuck at GRUB command line - GNU GRUB version 2.06-3~deb11u2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

So a couple days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my hp2000. Prior to that I installed Debian, then realized I needed Ubuntu (trying to set up Home Assistant for a home automation project). Anyway, the install seemed to be successful, but when I shutdown and restarted my computer I get stuck at the "GNU GRUB version 2.06-3~deb11u2" screen. I've spent quite a few hours over the last 2 days trying to resolve this, but as a newbie I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed with all the information and "help" articles. Most recently I came across [Stuck at GRUB command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line) but it seems a bit antiquated for my situation. Anyroad, any advice you all might offer would be much appreciated.

Attached is an image that will hopefully shed some light on what I've learned so far.[Image of grub screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhm6P.jpg)

Able to access Boot Manager using escape + F9. [Boot manager image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEley.jpg)

Comment: Adjust the boot-order in UEFI-settings to boot Ubuntu first.

Comment: @mook765 I've tried this and am not sure how. When I access BIOS I no longer have the option to change boot order. Not sure how to set boot-order in GRUB.

Comment: Not grub but UEFI. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios settings And if you cannot get to UEFI menus, then you left fast boot on in UEFI and have to turn it off. You may be able to "cold" boot, or not "warm" reboot. Fully shutdown system, drain all power & boot & immediate press keys to get into UEFI. It seems you installed grub differently and system it defaulting to boot grub left over from Debian. Also run report from this, to see details of your installs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: It's not the boot-order in grub, you are using the grub from debian, but you need to use the one from Ubuntu, thus you need to adjust boot-order in bios. Alternatively you  could try `sudo efibootmgr` from your installation media in "try without installing"-mode. Take a look at `man efibootmgr` and [thi question](https://askubuntu.com/q/485261/590937).

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for your response! I'll try Mook765's suggestion first and if it doesn't work, will try yours.

Comment: @mook765 Your idea of using escape + F9 worked! I loaded Boot Manager but now I'm not sure what option to choose as there are 2 Ubuntu choices. See attached image above in the original post.

Comment: @Jon It was @oldfred's suggestion, not mine. From your picture we can't know what the difference between this two entries is except the spelling. I suggest you try it out, maybe try the second one first. We could see to which file an entry belongs from `efibootmgr -v`-output.

Comment: @mook765 Okay, thank you for correcting me - and kudos to @oldfred! I chose the second entry and was able to login to Ubuntu. However, after restarting I'm back at the same GRUB screen. Am I going to have to repeat the steps again to be able to log in each time? Or how do I set the Boot Manager to automatically select the second entry. Also, as a sidenote, I tried the first entry and it immediately loaded GRUB. :-/

Comment: @Jon Did you save the change in your BIOS? Obviously not. You can also use `efibootmgr` to adjust boot-order when you're logged in. You can also use `efibootmgr` to remove not working entries, see https://askubuntu.com/a/63613/590937 and `man efibootmgr`

Comment: @mook765 I have not yet saved the change in my BIOS. Will do that using the efibootmgr and update  this thread afterwards Many thanks!

Comment: @mook765 Sorry for the delay. I tried follwing the instructions in the link you provided askubuntu.com/a/63613/590937 (not sure what 'man efibootmgr' is for) and I was able to remove the 'Ubuntu' (capitalized/problematic entry) as well as the 'Debian' one. I restarted and it started to boot into Ubuntu then it jumped to Grub. So I went through the steps again (efimgr showed that the incorrect boot order had been restored), this time changing the boot order (placing 'ubuntu' first) and Voilá!! No problems logging in!

Comment: @mook765 Also, I tried the additional steps that the article listed to "delete the ubuntu subdirectory in the EFI partition to prevent the UEFI firmware from restoring the entry into the BootOrder." and was unable to find the dev/sda2 partition. Ah well, it's working and I owe it in large part to your (and oldfred's) help. Many thanks!!

Comment: @mook765 Do I need to mark this question as answered? If so, I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: The way to mark a question as answered is to write an answer and accept the answer. You can do this yourself, if it's too much for you, don't worry, the main thing is that your problem is solved.

Comment: @mook765 Okay, so I was mistaken. The boot order IS resetting when I power off and restart. I've gone through the steps outlined at https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi/63613#63613 however a few notes: When I "add to the kernel EFI support" using 'sudo modprobe efivars' there is no apparent effect. Should there be something in terminal confirming that a change was made? Also, when I reach "Now we have to find the directory Ubuntu..." I don't know how to find the Ubuntu directory.

Comment: @mook765 When I run pwd is shows I'm in /home/jon and I'm able to find /home/jon -name "Downloads" -type d

Comment: When I run pwd is shows I'm in /home/jon and I'm able to `find /home/jon -name "Downloads" -type d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got it to work - for the time being anyway. I was able to get into the Bios (insydeh20 version  f. 37) advanced configuration.

Steps:
1.) I toggled through System Time (by hitting Enter, but didn't make changes to the time)
2.) Did the same with System Date
3.) Selected System log and hit enter, then hit Escape (taking me back to Main)
4.) Arrowed over to Security

1. Selected Admin Password, hit Enter (brought up Set Administrator Password), Hit Enter 3 times (taking me back to Security)
2. Arrow down to Power-On Password, hit Enter (brought up Set Power On Password), Hit Enter 3 times (taking me back to Security)
   5.) System Configuration: selected Language (hit Enter on English, then Enter again taking me back to System Configuration)
   6.) Same process as above with Virtualization Technology (disabled), Fan Always on, Action Keys Mode (enabled)
   7.)[Picture of where changes were made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qowtB.jpg)Then when I select Boot options I NOW have the  ability to change UEFI boot order, etc. (before there were only 3 options under boot options)
3. Changed POST Hotkey delay (sec) from <0> to <10>
4. CD-ROM boot
5. Internal network Adapter Boot
6. etc.
7. I ended up disabling Secure Boot (maybe not a good idea?)
8. I cleared all secure Boot Keys (had to enter a code that was provided)
9. Load HP Factory Default Keys
   8.) Don't know if this is the correct / safe way to work around the “Stuck at GRUB command line - GNU GRUB” problem but now I'm able to shut down/restart with no hangups.